# what is the shorcut for Mean uncrease

Tags: mesh

With the face or edges selected. In edit mode when press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> i can make Mean Crease to make the edge sharper. But after making the crease if i want to remove the crease i have to go in N panel in Edges Data to give a value 0. Like the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut is there any Mean uncrease or say i want remove crease. Any suggestion or help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Press shift+e and type 0 to set the crease back to 0

Comment: @Tim it does not work

Comment: Yeah, sorry got that wrong. Its -1 rather than 0 which you need to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I think you can do is press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>.

The reason for this is that creasing does an offset from the current crease value. Pressing <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> offsets from the maximum crease value an edge could have, which is '1', to '0'.